# When would we want a non-persistent Preference?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm trying to wrap my head around persistency when it comes to Android preferences. There's an attribute persistent, which can be either true or false. If true, the preference is committed to shared preferences. How can a preference be used if it's not persistent?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could (ab-)use Preferences as menu items (make them clickable to launch some other action) or to display some info, e.g. application version etc.

In this case, you don't want them to be stored in the xml file.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. It appears that the persistent attribute is true by default for preferences, but I cannot find this stated in the documentation anywhere. Should I be explicitly setting this attribute to true?

Comment: There is also `setDefaultValue` which sadly has this requirement to be able to work, no? Sadly though, I couldn't figure out how to use it properly.

Comment: Probably, you have figured it out by now. Just adding `app:persistent="false"` to any `Preference` item will work. Values won't persisted for that `Preference`